# How to convert a char to a String?

Tags: java, string, char, type-conversion

I have a `char` and I need a `String`. How do I convert from one to the other?

Comment: Downvoted? Why would I ask such an easy question? Because Google lacks a really obvious search result for this question. By putting this here we'll change that.

Comment: i completely agree with your opinion. I up voted this to get rid of the negative vote. I firmly believe in making googling topics like this easier for everyone. =)

Comment: Your position is arguable (meta question?); I guess we can assume the downvote is for "lack of research".

Comment: I did do research. I had to click on a few search results and look at lengthy blog posts and ads.

Comment: Did your research include reading the documentation of the String class?

Comment: @DJClayworth Most SO questions could be answered with RTFM, but that's not very helpful. Why not let people who find the question upvote it and let things take their course?

Comment: @PaulBellora Only that StackOverflow has become **the first stop** for research. If there is a StackOverlfow link in the first 10 Google Results I com here.

Answer (score 694):

You can use [`Character.toString(char)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#toString-char-). Note that this method simply returns a call to [`String.valueOf(char)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf-char-), which also works.

As others have noted, string concatenation works as a shortcut as well:

```
String s = "" + 's';
```

But this compiles down to:

```
String s = new StringBuilder().append("").append('s').toString();
```

which is less efficient because the `StringBuilder` is backed by a `char[]` (over-allocated by [`StringBuilder()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/lang/StringBuilder.java#StringBuilder.%3Cinit%3E%28%29) to `16`), only for that array to be defensively copied by the resulting `String`.

`String.valueOf(char)` "gets in the back door" by wrapping the `char` in a single-element array and passing it to the package private constructor [`String(char[], boolean)`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/lang/String.java#String.%3Cinit%3E%28char%5B%5D%2Cboolean%29), which avoids the array copy.

Comment: I think the shortcut compiles down to: ``new StringBuilder("").append('s').toString();``

Comment: @BinkanSalaryman using javac 1.8.0_51-b16 and then javap to decompile, I see the constructor/method calls I have in the answer. What are you using?

Answer (score 276):

I've got of the following <strike>five</strike> *six* methods to do it.

```
// Method #1
String stringValueOf = String.valueOf('c'); // most efficient

// Method #2
String stringValueOfCharArray = String.valueOf(new char[]{x});

// Method #3
String characterToString = Character.toString('c');

// Method #4
String characterObjectToString = new Character('c').toString();

// Method #5
// Although this approach seems very simple, 
// this is less efficient because the concatenation
// expands to a StringBuilder.
String concatBlankString = 'c' + "";

// Method #6
String fromCharArray = new String(new char[]{x});
```

> Note: [Character.toString(char)](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Character.java#Character.toString%28char%29) returns [String.valueOf(char)](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java#String.valueOf%28char%29). So effectively both are same.

`String.valueOf(char[] value)` invokes `new String(char[] value)`, which in turn sets the `value` char array.

```
public String(char value[]) {
    this.value = Arrays.copyOf(value, value.length);
}
```

On the other hand `String.valueOf(char value)` invokes the following **package private constructor.**

```
String(char[] value, boolean share) {
    // assert share : "unshared not supported";
    this.value = value;
}
```

*Source code from `String.java` in [Java 8 source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/lang/String.java)*

> Hence `String.valueOf(char)` seems to be most efficient method, in terms of both memory and speed, for converting `char` to `String`.

Sources:

1. [How to convert primitive char to String in Java](https://deepumohan.com/tech/java-how-to-convert-primitive-char-to/)
2. [How to convert Char to String in Java with Example](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2012/02/how-to-convert-char-to-string-in-java.html)

Answer (score 59):

Below are various ways to convert to char c to String s (in decreasing order of speed and efficiency)

```
char c = 'a';
String s = String.valueOf(c);             // fastest + memory efficient
String s = Character.toString(c);
String s = new String(new char[]{c});
String s = String.valueOf(new char[]{c});
String s = new Character(c).toString();
String s = "" + c;                        // slowest + memory inefficient
```

Comment: someone tested this?

Answer (score 34):

Use any of the following:

```
String str = String.valueOf('c');
String str = Character.toString('c');
String str = 'c' + "";
```

Answer (score 33):

Use the `Character.toString()` method like so:

```
char mChar = 'l';
String s = Character.toString(mChar);
```

Answer (score 19):

As @WarFox stated - there are 6 methods to convert char to string. However, the fastest one would be via concatenation, despite answers above stating that it is `String.valueOf`. Here is benchmark that proves that:

```
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.Throughput)
@Fork(1)
@State(Scope.Thread)
@Warmup(iterations = 10, time = 1, batchSize = 1000, timeUnit = TimeUnit.SECONDS)
@Measurement(iterations = 10, time = 1, batchSize = 1000, timeUnit = TimeUnit.SECONDS)
public class CharToStringConversion {

    private char c = 'c';

    @Benchmark
    public String stringValueOf() {
        return String.valueOf(c);
    }

    @Benchmark
    public String stringValueOfCharArray() {
        return String.valueOf(new char[]{c});
    }

    @Benchmark
    public String characterToString() {
        return Character.toString(c);
    }

    @Benchmark
    public String characterObjectToString() {
        return new Character(c).toString();
    }

    @Benchmark
    public String concatBlankStringPre() {
        return c + "";
    }

    @Benchmark
    public String concatBlankStringPost() {
        return "" + c;
    }

    @Benchmark
    public String fromCharArray() {
        return new String(new char[]{c});
    }
}
```

And result:

```
Benchmark                                        Mode  Cnt       Score      Error  Units
CharToStringConversion.characterObjectToString  thrpt   10   82132.021 ± 6841.497  ops/s
CharToStringConversion.characterToString        thrpt   10  118232.069 ± 8242.847  ops/s
CharToStringConversion.concatBlankStringPost    thrpt   10  136960.733 ± 9779.938  ops/s
CharToStringConversion.concatBlankStringPre     thrpt   10  137244.446 ± 9113.373  ops/s
CharToStringConversion.fromCharArray            thrpt   10   85464.842 ± 3127.211  ops/s
CharToStringConversion.stringValueOf            thrpt   10  119281.976 ± 7053.832  ops/s
CharToStringConversion.stringValueOfCharArray   thrpt   10   86563.837 ± 6436.527  ops/s
```

As you can see, the fastest one would be `c + ""` or `"" + c`;

```
VM version: JDK 1.8.0_131, VM 25.131-b11
```

This performance difference is due to `-XX:+OptimizeStringConcat` optimization. You can read about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42193955/why-is-string-concatenation-faster-than-string-valueof-for-converting-an-integer).

Answer (score 18):

Try this: `Character.toString(aChar)` or just this: `aChar + ""`

Answer (score 5):

We have various ways to convert a `char` to `String`. **One** way is to make use of static method `toString()` in `Character` class:

```
char ch = 'I'; 
String str1 = Character.toString(ch);
```

Actually this `toString` method internally makes use of `valueOf` method from `String` class which makes use of char array:

```
public static String toString(char c) {
    return String.valueOf(c);
}
```

So **second** way is to use this directly:

```
String str2 = String.valueOf(ch);
```

This `valueOf` method in `String` class makes use of char array:

```
public static String valueOf(char c) {
        char data[] = {c};
        return new String(data, true);
}
```

So the **third** way is to make use of an anonymous array to wrap a single character and then passing it to `String` constructor:

```
String str4 = new String(new char[]{ch});
```

The **fourth** way is to make use of concatenation:

```
String str3 = "" + ch;
```

This will actually make use of `append` method from `StringBuilder` class which is actually preferred when we are doing concatenation in a loop.

Answer (score 4):

Here are a few methods, in no particular order:

```
char c = 'c';

String s = Character.toString(c); // Most efficient way

s = new Character(c).toString(); // Same as above except new Character objects needs to be garbage-collected

s = c + ""; // Least efficient and most memory-inefficient, but common amongst beginners because of its simplicity

s = String.valueOf(c); // Also quite common

s = String.format("%c", c); // Not common

Formatter formatter = new Formatter();
s = formatter.format("%c", c).toString(); // Same as above
formatter.close();
```

Answer (score 2):

**I am converting Char Array to String**

```
Char[] CharArray={ 'A', 'B', 'C'};
String text = String.copyValueOf(CharArray);
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15016514)

Comment: I am Converting Char Array to String @pczeus

Answer (score 1):

```
  char vIn = 'A';
  String vOut = Character.toString(vIn);
```

For these types of conversion, I have site bookmarked called https://www.converttypes.com/
It helps me quickly get the conversion code for most of the languages I use.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried the suggestions but ended up implementing it as follows

```
editView.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilter()
        {
            @Override
            public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end,
                                       Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend)
            {
                String prefix = "http://";

                //make sure our prefix is visible
                String destination = dest.toString();

                //Check If we already have our prefix - make sure it doesn't
                //get deleted
                if (destination.startsWith(prefix) && (dstart <= prefix.length() - 1))
                {
                    //Yep - our prefix gets modified - try preventing it.
                    int newEnd = (dend >= prefix.length()) ? dend : prefix.length();

                    SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder(
                            destination.substring(dstart, newEnd));
                    builder.append(source);
                    if (source instanceof Spanned)
                    {
                        TextUtils.copySpansFrom(
                                (Spanned) source, 0, source.length(), null, builder, newEnd);
                    }

                    return builder;
                }
                else
                {
                    //Accept original replacement (by returning null)
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just chipping in to add that with rust 1.46.0 you can convert a char into a string like so:

```rust
let string = String::from('a');
```

Answer (score -2):

To convert a `char` to a `String`, you can use the `String.valueOf` method.

To convert a `String` to a `char`, you can use the `String.charAt` method.

```java
char character = 'a';
String string = String.valueOf(character);
```

```java
String string = "a";
char character = string.charAt(0);
```