# How can i use IndexOf with a referenced char java

Tags: java, char, indexof

I am trying to use the indexOf method to find if a char is in a word but since the char cannot be dereferenced i assumed it should be converted to a String i tried using these [Methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8172420/how-to-convert-a-char-to-a-string-in-java) but it does not seem to be comparing accurately - how should i be using a referenced char in 'indexOF'. here is my code, if this is a stupid problem with my code logic then i apologise

```
  guess = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter letter ").toUpperCase().charAt(0);

    if((String.valueOf(guess)).indexOf(word.toUpperCase())>=0)
    {
        for(int k = 0; k<word.length(); k++)
        {
            if(guess==charwo[k])
            {
                charda[k]=charwo[k];                 
            }           
        }
    }
    else
    {
        guesses = guesses-1;
        System.out.println("guesses left "+guesses);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, I think this line is backwards:

```
if((String.valueOf(guess)).indexOf(word.toUpperCase())>=0)
```

should be

```
if(word.toUpperCase().indexOf(String.valueOf(guess).toUpperCase) >=0)
```

you could also do

```
if(word.toUpperCase().contains(String.valueOf(guess).toUpperCase))
```

Comment: if(word.toUpperCase().contains(String.valueOf(guess).toUpperCase)) - this seemed to actually work better for me thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

I think you're using `indexOf` the wrong way around. Assuming your looking for the index of `guess` in `word` (the other way around doesn't really make sense), it should be:

```
word.toUpperCase().indexOf(guess)
```

No dereferencing problems here since there an [`indexOf(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28int%29) function.

[`contains`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) would probably make for slightly more readable code, unfortunately it takes a `CharSequence` parameter (superclass of `String`), so you'd need to convert `guess` to `String` in this case. The way I usually convert primitives to `String` like this:

```
word.toUpperCase().contains(""+guess)
```

Though I'm not saying it's better than `String.valueOf`, I just use it because it's less typing.