# Java character to String

Tags: java, java-6

I tried multiple versions, including several solutions found here on StackOverflow, but I always get numbers instead of the characters in the console. For a homework in my uni, we need to invert the characters in a string. But creating the new string seems to be not so easy.

I tried using a StringBuilder,

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
// ...
builder.append(c); // c of type char
```

String concatenation,

```
System.out.print("" + c); // c of type char
```

and even String.valueOf(),

```
System.out.print(String.valueOf(c)); // c of type char
```

and each of them again with explicit conversion to `char`. But I always get the ordinal number of the characters in a sequence instead of the actual characters as output in the console. How do I correctly build a new string from `char`s?

```
/**
 * Praktikum Informatik - IN0002
 * Arbeitsblatt 02 - Aufgabe 2.6 (Buchstaben invertieren)
 */

public class H0206 {

    public static String readLine() {
        final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            // Read until a newline character was found.
            while (true) {
                int c = System.in.read();
                if (c == '\n')
                    break;
                builder.append(c);
            }
        }
        catch (java.io.IOException e) {
            ; // We assume that the end of the stream was reached.
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Read the first line from the terminal.
        final String input = readLine();

        // Create a lowercase and uppercase version of the line.
        final String lowercase = input.toLowerCase();
        final String uppercase = input.toUpperCase();

        // Convert the string on the fly and print it out.
        for (int i=0; i < input.length(); ++i) {
            // If the character is the same in the lowercase
            // version, we'll use the uppercase version instead.
            char c = input.charAt(i);
            if (lowercase.charAt(i) == c)
                c = uppercase.charAt(i);
            System.out.print(Character.toString(c));
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

Comment: `c` of type `char`? The one I see in your example is an `int`. Also, what does `System.in.read()`  do?

Comment: [`String#valueOf()` shoud work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8172420/how-to-convert-a-char-to-a-string-in-java)... Are you sure you character is not a digit, e.g. `'4'`?

Comment: `c` may held a character data but it is certainly of type `int` and not `char`. Convert it to `char` like this: `char ch = (char) c;`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Where is the `int`? I am trying to convert `c`, not `i`. `System.out.print(Character.toString(c));` -> c is a `char` here

Comment: @icza Ohhhh I searched for the problem in the wrong function. :) Thank you! I thought the problem was in main(), but its in readLine()

Answer (score 2):

The problem I see with the sample code you provided is here:

```
int c = System.in.read();
if (c == '\n')
   break;
builder.append(c);
```

The way you call the method, [Stringbuilder.append(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#append(int)) will be called. As the javadoc says, "the overall effect is exactly as if the argument were converted to a string by the method String.valueOf(int), and the characters of that string were then appended to this character sequence". Casting the integer-value to char like this will result in the desired behavior:

```
int c = System.in.read();
if (c == '\n')
   break;
builder.append((char) c);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample how to invert a String, there is another options, i think this one is more didacticism

```
 public static void main(final String[] args) {
    String text = "This is a string that will be inverted";
    char[] charArray = text.toCharArray();
    char[] invertedCharArray = new char[charArray.length];
    for (int i = 1; i <= charArray.length; i++) {
        char c = charArray[charArray.length - i];
        invertedCharArray[i - 1] = c;
    }
    System.out.println(text);
    System.out.println(new String(invertedCharArray));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 try { // Read until a newline character was found.
        while (true) {
            int c = System.in.read();
            if (c == '\n') break;
            builder.append(c);
        }
```

From the sample you gave, I can see that this is causing the problem. Because you are reading the `char` input as an `int`, it converts the char to its ordinal value so it can be stored (and therefore used) as an integer.

In [public final class StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)  you're calling `append(int i)`, which returns `int`. If `int c = System.out.read();` 
is required for this to be declared as an integer, you can cast c to a char.

```
char ch = (char)c;
builder.append(ch)
```

If needed, this leaves c as an integer and stores its "original value" (What it was before it was turned into an `int`, i.e. the key pressed) in a variable if needed. If you only need to add it to the string, without reusing it for any reason, you can cast c to a char directly with `append((char) c)`.