# Individual array elements to string in Java

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have an array of type char which has some characters stored in it. I want to take each individual character and store it in a string.
How do i do that?

Comment: I don't want to store all the elements in a single string. I want to store each character in a different string

Comment: Do this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8172420/how-to-convert-a-char-to-a-string-in-java) for each element of your array

Comment: for (char c : myCharAry){
  String tmpCharacterAsString = new String(c);
}

Answer (score 1):

```
   public String[] charArrayToStringArray(char[] c){
        String[] s = new String[c.length];

        for(int i = 0; i < c.length; i++){
            s[i] = String.valueOf(c[i]);
        }

        return s;
    }
```

A simpler way would be:

```
char[] c = new char[]{'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'};
String[] s  = new String(c).split("");
```

It works, but it adds an empty string in position 0 of the array.

Answer (score 0):

You can store your strings in another array:

```
 String[] stringArray = new String[charsArray.length];
  for (int i=0; i<charsArray.length; i++){
    stringArray[i] = "" +charsArray[i];
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
char[] charArray = {'a', 'b', 'c'};
String str = String.valueOf(charArray);
System.out.println(str);
```

or

```
String sTest="";
for (char c : charArray) {
    sTest+=c;
}
System.out.println(sTest);
```