# printing out specific letters from chosen items from an array (Java)

Tags: java, arrays

I'm very, VERY new to Java so apologies if this is something very obvious that I just fail to see. I'm doing a course on Java at my uni and we've just started to cover arrays. There was a simple exercise we were assigned:

> Write a program that creates an array (names) with the names Bob, Ann
>   & Tom.  The program should go through the array and print out the
>   first letter of each name as a word ("BAT").

We are given a way to do it using a for loop and this method works:

```
String [] names = {"Bob", "Ann", "Tom"};
String initials = "";
for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++)
{
     initials = initials + names[i].charAt(0);
}
System.out.print(initials);
```

But I wanted to do it in another way, using **char.At()** method:

```
  System.out.print(names[0].charAt(0) + names[1].charAt(0) + names[2].charAt(0) + "\n");
```

However, instead of "BAT", the output is 215. Can anyone explain why this is happening and what's wrong with my code? Many, many thanks!

====
EDIT:

I have now tried the four solutions that chsdk, jgr208, Pier-Alexandre Bouchard and Gorfield suggested, however none of them works. I still end up with 215. I've also tried methods of converting chars to strings mentioned in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8172420/how-to-convert-a-char-to-a-string-in-java); I still end up with 215. This got me thinking maybe there is something wrong with my declaration of the array? Any suggestions?
Code details of what I've tried below.

```
String [] names = {"Bob", "Ann", "Tom"};
String initials = "";
initials = initials + names[0].charAt(0);
initials = initials + names[1].charAt(0);
initials = initials + names[2].charAt(0);
System.out.print(initials);
```

= 215

```
String [] names = {"Bob", "Ann", "Tom"};
String a = names[0].charAt(0) + "";
String b = names[1].charAt(0) + "";
String c = names[2].charAt(0) + "";
System.out.print("" + a + "" + b + "" + c + "");
```

= 215

```
String [] names = {"Bob", "Ann", "Tom"};
String a = new Character(names[0].charAt(0)).toString();
String b = new Character(names[1].charAt(0)).toString();
String c = new Character(names[2].charAt(0)).toString();
System.out.print("" + a + "" + b + "" + c + "");
```

= 215

```
String [] names = {"Bob", "Ann", "Tom"};
String a = Character.toString(names[0].charAt(0));
String b = Character.toString(names[1].charAt(0));
String c = Character.toString(names[2].charAt(0));
System.out.print("" + a + "" + b + "" + c + "");
```

= 215

```
String [] names = {"Bob", "Ann", "Tom"};
String a = String.valueOf(names[0].charAt(0));
String b = String.valueOf(names[1].charAt(0));
String c = String.valueOf(names[2].charAt(0));
System.out.println(a + "" + b + "" + c);
```

= 215

```
String [] names = {"Bob", "Ann", "Tom"};
System.out.printf("%s%s%s",names[0].charAt(0),names[1].charAt(0),names[2].charAt(0));
```

= 215

```
String [] names = {"Bob", "Ann", "Tom"};
System.out.print(names[0].substring(0));
System.out.print("\n");
System.out.print(names[1].substring(0));
System.out.print("\n");
System.out.print(names[2].substring(0));
System.out.println("");
```

= 215

```
String [] names = {"Bob", "Ann", "Tom"};
String initials = "";
initials+=names[0].charAt(0);
initials+=names[1].charAt(0); 
initials+=names[2].charAt(0);
System.out.print(initials);
```

= 215

```
String [] names = {"Bob", "Ann", "Tom"};
System.out.print("" + names[0].charAt(0) + "" + names[1].charAt(0) + "" + names[2].charAt(0) + "\n");`
```

= 215

Comment: I think that is the ASCII code for the letter

Comment: Are you sure you are recompiling your code? I tried some of the solutions above and am getting "BAT"

Answer (score 0):

The compiler evaluates the constant expression `'B' + 'A' + 'T'` by promoting each of the char-valued operands (`'B'`, `'A'` and `'T'`) to int values through a process known as *widening primitive conversion*.

Take a look to the ASCII table (http://www.asciitable.com/) to get the value of each char:

- B = 66
- A = 65
- T = 84

So `'B' + 'A' + 'T'` is equivalent to the int constant  `66 + 65 + 84 = 215.`

If you want `BAT` to be printed, you need to create a new string. Something like this should work:

```
System.out.print("" + names[0].charAt(0) + names[1].charAt(0) + names[2].charAt(0) + "\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

215 is the ASCII summation of B+A+T (66+65+84), basically instead of concatenating characters it thinks you are adding them. You can get around this by using `printf()` instead of a normal print:

```
System.out.printf("%s%s%s",names[0].charAt(0),names[1].charAt(0),names[2].charAt(0));
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code is a possible solution:

```
System.out.print(names[0].substring(0));
System.out.print(names[1].substring(0));
System.out.print(names[2].substring(0));
System.out.println("");
```

Where you just print out each letter separate and then use `print("\n")` to do the new line

Answer (score 0):

You have to concatenate those letters like this:

```
System.out.print(names[0].charAt(0) +""+ names[1].charAt(0) +""+ names[2].charAt(0) + "\n");
```

Because in your case you are summing the ASCII codes of those Chars instead of concatenating them, that's why you got 215.

Or assign their values to your `initials`string, then print it:

```
initials+=names[0].charAt(0);
initials+=names[1].charAt(0); 
initials+=names[2].charAt(0);
System.out.print(intitials);
```