# How to Check Every Letter as a String

Tags: java

I'm failing the following test case:

```
@Test (timeout=3000) public void gatenot_0(){
    GateNot g = new GateNot (new Wire("inw"), new Wire("outa"));
    g.feed("0");
    boolean ans = g.propagate();
    assertEquals(sigs1, g.read());
  }
```

which says `"Invalid character"` - Exception thrown by the following method:

```
public static List <Signal> fromString(String inps)
    {
        List<Signal> values = new ArrayList<Signal>();
        for(int i = 0; i < inps.length(); i++)
        {
            if(inps.charAt(i) != '1' && inps.charAt(i) != '0' 
                    && inps.charAt(i) != 'X' && inps.charAt(i) != 'x'
                    && inps.charAt(i) != ' ' && inps.charAt(i) != '\t')
                throw new ExceptionLogicMalformedSignal(inps.charAt(0), "Invalid character!");

            else if(inps.charAt(i) == '1')
                values.add(HI);
            else if(inps.charAt(i) == '0')
                values.add(LO);
            else if(inps.charAt(i) == 'X')
                values.add(X);
            else if(inps.charAt(i) == 'x')
                values.add(X);



        }
        return values;

    }
```

Everytime I pass something including "0" or "1" it throws Exception So, should I check every letter of String inps as a String instead of `charAt()`. If yes, how should I check that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: your code does not show how your are calling `fromString(String inps)`

Comment: can you show the complete string that throws the exception

Comment: Change `inps.charAt(0)` to `inps.charAt(i)` to see the character that's actually causing the error.

Answer (score 1):

To check every letter as a string you could use

```
Character.toString(inps.charAt(i))
```

instead of just `inps.charAt(i)`

I would recommend storing it in a variable for each iteration instead of calling many times.

You could also do

```
String.valueOf(inps.charAt(i))
```

There is a shortcut

```
inps.charAt(i) + ""
```

And yet another way:

```
inps.substring(i, i + 1)
```

Note that if you end of converting each letter to string, you should use the `.equals` method when comparing them.

For more information about this, you can look at [How to convert a char to a String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8172420/how-to-convert-a-char-to-a-string-in-java)