# Why is String concatenation faster than String.valueOf for converting an Integer to a String?

Tags: java, performance, microbenchmark

I have a benchmark :

```
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.Throughput)
@Fork(1)
@State(Scope.Thread)
@Warmup(iterations = 10, time = 1, timeUnit = TimeUnit.SECONDS, batchSize = 1000)
@Measurement(iterations = 40, time = 1, timeUnit = TimeUnit.SECONDS, batchSize = 1000)
public class StringConcatTest {

    private int aInt;

    @Setup
    public void prepare() {
        aInt = 100;
    }

    @Benchmark
    public String emptyStringInt() {
        return "" + aInt;
    }

    @Benchmark
    public String valueOfInt() {
        return String.valueOf(aInt);
    }

}
```

And here is result :

```
Benchmark                                          Mode  Cnt      Score      Error  Units
StringConcatTest.emptyStringInt                   thrpt   40  66045.741 ± 1306.280  ops/s
StringConcatTest.valueOfInt                       thrpt   40  43947.708 ± 1140.078  ops/s
```

It shows that concatenating of empty string with integer number is 30% faster than calling String.value(100).
I understand that "" + 100 converted to

```
new StringBuilder().append(100).toString()
```

and `-XX:+OptimizeStringConcat` optimization is applied that makes it fast. What I do not understand is why `valueOf` itself is slower than concatenation.
Can someone explain what exactly is happening and why "" + 100 is faster. What magic does `OptimizeStringConcat` make?

Comment: `"" + 100` is probably much clearer for the compiler to recognize as a constant...

Comment: You could look at the source code for `valueOf`. I'm pretty sure it tries to detect object types, which means autoboxing your int primitive and such

Comment: One of those is a method call.  The other, the compiler can compile however it wants.

Comment: The JIT could, but it seems unlikely to eliminate the entire thing.

Comment: @LouisWasserman it is not compiled to constant. It is compiled to `StringBuider()` construction.

Comment: JIT won't usually kick in on smaller runs very much.  What sort of warmup did you give the benchmark?

Comment: @LewBloch you can see it in benchmark. JMH avoids JIT "kicks". @cricket_007 I looked inside `valueOf` but It doesn't answer my question.

Comment: @DmitriyDumanskiy, not necessarily; the compiler documentation is pretty vague about it.  [Ask me how I know.](http://openjdk.5641.n7.nabble.com/String-concatenation-tweaks-td219080.html)

Comment: @LouisWasserman I can say for sure, as constant expression will have millions of scores (ops/s) in benchmark.

Comment: I agree that doesn't appear to be the case here.  It's not necessarily true in general, and not necessarily true in future compiler versions, because of the discussion I linked to above.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Thanks for link. Very interesting reading :).

Comment: JVM probably does not have an "intrinsic" understanding of `String.valueOf()` - the method isn't used often enough; therefore the method body is executed faithfully every time.

Comment: @cricket_007 `String.valueOf()` has numerous overloads, which recognize the argument type at compile-time. There is no autoboxing or runtime object type detection.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As you've mentioned, HotSpot JVM has `-XX:+OptimizeStringConcat` optimization that recognizes StringBuilder pattern and replaces it with highly tuned hand-written IR graph, while `String.valueOf()` relies on general compiler optimizations.

I've found the following key differences by analyzing the generated assembly code:

- Optimized concat does not zero `char[]` array created for the result string, while the array created by `Integer.toString` is cleared after allocation just like any other regular object.
- Optimized concat translates digits to chars by simple [addition of '0' constant](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/e765322578aa/src/share/vm/opto/stringopts.cpp#l1315), while `Integer.getChars` uses [table lookup](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/8c93eb3fa1c0/src/share/classes/java/lang/Integer.java#l458) with the related array bounds check etc.

There are other minor differences in the implementation of [`PhaseStringOpts::int_getChars`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/e765322578aa/src/share/vm/opto/stringopts.cpp#l1214) vs. [`Integer.getChars`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/8c93eb3fa1c0/src/share/classes/java/lang/Integer.java#l433), but I guess they are not that significant for performance.

---

BTW, if you take a bigger number (e.g. 1234567890), the performance difference will be negligible because of an [extra loop](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/8c93eb3fa1c0/src/share/classes/java/lang/Integer.java#l443) in `Integer.getChars` that converts two digits at once.