# How do I make a methods that splits a String into individual letters of type String?

Tags: java, string, methods, char

In the following snippet:

```
static Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
static String str;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    str = userInput.nextLine();

}

 public String wordSplitter() {     
    char b;     

    for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length(); i += 1) 
    b = str.charAt(i);
    return b;       
}
```

the statement "**return b;**" gives me an error because my method should return a String, but **b** is a char.

So how do I somehow make b into a String? Or is there a better way to split Strings into letters of type String?

thanks

Comment: Lots of way to do this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8172420/how-to-convert-a-char-to-a-string

Comment: Is b being overwritten on purpose? Also, is wordSplitter instance method on purpose?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? What is the purpose of `wordSplitter` method?

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
public String splitStringIntoLetters(){
        String toBeSplit = "abcdefg";
        char [] toBeSplitChar = toBeSplit.toCharArray();
        return java.util.Arrays.toString(toBeSplitChar);
}
```

this returns something like:
[a, b, c, d, e, f, g]

Once you get the string just perform the operation that you want on the string.
e.g.

```
String testStr = splitStringIntoLetters();
System.out.println(testStr.replace("["," ").replace("]"," ").split(","));
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve that, you can use/return **Character.toString(b)** or **String.valueOf(b)** static methods.

[here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#toString-char-) and [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf-char-) the Doc

```
public String wordSplitter() {     
    char b;     
    ....// do something and assign b
    return Character.toString(b);       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public String wordSplitter() {     
    char b;     

    for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length(); i += 1) 
    b = String.valueOf(str.charAt(i));
    return b;       
}
```

You can try above code.

```
   String string = Character.toString(ch);
   String string = String.valueOf(ch);
```

This both above method can convert your character to String.
Hope this will helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it like these，first of all I think it should be `i<str.legth;` and you can handle it like this, `return b+"";`

Comment: ..?? forgot something??

Comment: Char plus " " is a string,it is convenient than other methods.

Answer (score 0):

Seems your code is mainly designed to eat CPU performance.

Normally you would replace :

```
for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length(); i += 1) 
    b = str.charAt(i); 
return b;
```

By

```
return str.charAt(numbers.length()-1);
```

And if you insist on returning a String you would do

```
 return String.valueOf(str.charAt(numbers.length()-1));
```

... but I struggle understanding what the purpose of this could be