# changing a character to string in java

Tags: java, string, char, contains

Within this method the String buildWord is used at `if(this.guessedLetters.contains(buildWord))`, when i run the testProgram with the main file, i get the incorrect results, but when I manually use `if(this.guessedLetters.contains("" + letter))`, it works.  My question is what is the difference here?? Why are these two not the same: `if(this.guessedLetters.contains(buildWord))`, and `if(this.guessedLetters.contains("" + letter))`

```
public String hiddenWord() {
    char letter = ' ';
    String hiddenWord = "";
    String buildWord = "" + letter;
    int i = 0;
    while (i < this.word.length()) {
        letter = this.word.charAt(i);
        if (this.guessedLetters.contains(buildWord))  { // **********
            hiddenWord += letter;
        } else  {
            hiddenWord += '_';
        }
        i++;
    }
    return hiddenWord;
}
```

Comment: the values are from the main method, the values are "A" "D" "S" "F" "D", the word used from a tutorial KISSA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is that `letter` gets updated in the loop, but `buildWord` doesn't and always is equal to the string `" "`. If you add `buildWord = "" + letter;` after you re-assign `letter`, then it will work:

```
while (i < this.word.length()) {
    letter = this.word.charAt(i);
    buildWord = "" + letter;           // <------------
    if (this.guessedLetters.contains(buildWord))
```

For more information on the different ways to convert a character to a string see [How to convert a char to a String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8172420/how-to-convert-a-char-to-a-string)

Comment: After changing it that way it works, I'm just still confuse how, char letter holds the updated value, how come **`String buildWord = " " + letter;`** doesn't get updated as well?  For example: if **`char letter = 'K';`** gets updated, how come, **`buildWord = " " + letter;`** isn't **`buildWord = " " + 'K';`**  and so forth as char letter gets updated?

Comment: No. When you set `buildWord = "" + letter`, it gets the **current value** of `letter` and concatenates it with the empty string. It doesn't keep updating `buildWord` as `letter` changes. What if `"" + letter` was more complex such as getting a value from a database: `String buildWord = GetDatabaseValue() + letter;` do you still think we should go and update `buildWord` when `letter` changes? How would it update, by going and fetching the new database value or using the old cached value? What if `GetDatabaseValue()` changes? How would it even know? You need to tell the computer what to do.

Comment: In your example, you are telling the computer to recalculate the value passed into `contains` by calling it with the expression `"" + letter`.

Answer (score 0):

Difference is String.contains(CharSequence  s) method will take only CharSequence as a parameter. CharSequence  is an interface and all Known Implementing Classes are:

> **CharBuffer, Segment, String, StringBuffer, StringBuilder**

you can pass **any one** of the above class as a parameter but not directly the **char** that's why when you are trying to convert letter(char) as a **buildWord**(String) it **accepts** as it is an implementation class of CharSequence.

for further reference   [CharSequence java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html) and 
[String java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)