# Converting char array to String. Java

Tags: java, arrays, string

Int a[] = {1,2};

String s = a.toString(); //what's going on here.

My output is

I@something for integer array.
C@something for char array.

How to I correctly convert any array into string.

Comment: How do you want to convert? Do you want to merge and convertor do you want to convert it individually?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert a char to a String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8172420/how-to-convert-a-char-to-a-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using `char[]` array? If it suits your need this would help you:

```
char[] chars = {'1', 'a'};

    String string = new String(chars);
    System.out.println(string);
```

`Output: 1a`

Comment: Thanks!, well this helped me.
But now only query that left is when i try

String s = a.toString(); 


What does string s store in itself.? When I print value of s it only gives me a string which is = I@4517d9a3 if array is integer. If array is of character then my output for string s is C@4517d9a3, similarly for double array, I get string a output as D@4517d9a3

what are these codes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Arrays.toString(array)`

Like for example :

```
Int a[] = {1,2};

System.out.println("Array as String:"+Arrays.toString(array))
```

It will output:

`Array as String:[1,2]`

Comment: What does string s store in itself.? When I print s it only gives me a string which is  = I@4517d9a3 if array is integer. If array is of character then my output for string s is C@4517d9a3, similarly for double array, I get string a output as D@4517d9a3

Comment: @DevShukla it will give you the address of the array

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own implementation for learning what is going on background.

```
int a[] = {1,2};
printArray(a);

public void printArray(int[] a) {
    System.out.print("Array={");
    for(int singleElement : a) {
        print(singleElement);
    }
    System.out.println("}");
}
```